# Forwarding incoming traffic to a pi to another port

Tags: networking, ethernet-port, port-forwarding

So I have my pi 3b connected to another device with an IP address of 192.168.250.1 via Ethernet (eth0). I set my static IP address to 192.168.250.100 so both could communicate. The device wants to communicate through port 502, but will accept communication from other ports. I am sending data through port 9600 to the device, but it only wants to send data back through port 502 to the pi. How can I forward the incoming data destined for port 502 on my pi to port 9600? Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: is this `forward the incoming data` using port forwarding on a router? I kind of got lost in the word soup you posted ... not sure which device is which and which port is being forwarded and where it's forwarded from etc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.